# i get this error in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, startapp

‪#‎ask‬
Exception: JNI: Init’d AndroidJavaClass with null ptr! UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass..ctor (IntPtr jclass) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:539) UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.get_JavaLangClass () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:517) UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:508) UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass._AndroidJavaClass (System.String className) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/AndroidJavaImpl.cs:528) UnityEngine.AndroidJavaClass..ctor (System.String className) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/AndroidJava.cs:93) StartApp.StartAppWrapper.getWrapper () (at Assets/StartAppWrapper.cs:112) StartApp.StartAppWrapper.loadAd (AdEventListener listener) (at Assets/StartAppWrapper.cs:123) StartApp.StartAppWrapper.loadAd () (at Assets/StartAppWrapper.cs:128) StartAppBackPlugin.Start () (at Assets/StartAppBackPlugin.cs:9)

Comment: An Android plugin is trying to execute in the editor. Either stop that from happening or delete the plugin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are only running any Android Java or JNI helper class inside `#if UNITY_ANDROID` or in the Android device, not in Unity Editor.

You can use the pre-processor to prevent run Android Java helper API from running in the Editor or in any other platform.

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
//your Android class code here AndroidJavaClass
#endif
```